# Laravel 5.2 Looping How to prevent duplicate result?

Tags: laravel

Scenario is zone contain few cities, I have a problem in my edit form.

The problem is I need to make city belons to zone `selected=true` and the other city which dont belong to zone in default option.

So I have 2 loops like this

```
@foreach($cities as $city)
    @foreach($zone->cities as $zone_city)
        @if($city->id == $zone_city->id)
            <option value="{{ $city->id }}" selected="true">{{ $city->name }}</option>
        @endif  
    @endforeach
//if current city id not yet printed before then
<option value="{{ $city->id }}">{{ $city->name }}</option>
@endforeach
```

`$cities` is all city passed from controller the value is `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`, and `$zone->cities` is city which belongs to zone the value is `1, 3, 5`.

With the above code I get this result

```
<option value="1" selected="true">Surabaya</option>
<option value="1">Surabaya</option>     
<option value="2">Sidoarjo</option>

<option value="3" selected="true">Malang</option>
<option value="3">Malang</option>

<option value="4" selected="true">Gresik</option>
<option value="4">Gresik</option>       
<option value="5">Madura</option>
```

the result I expected is

```
<option value="1" selected="true">Surabaya</option>
<option value="2">Sidoarjo</option>

<option value="3" selected="true">Malang</option>

<option value="4" selected="true">Gresik</option>
<option value="5">Madura</option>
```

How to fix my looping code logic?

Thanks, any help appreciated.

**UPDATED**

Here is my edit controller

```
public function zone_edit($id)
{
    $zone = Zone::find($id);
    $cities = City::all();
    return view('backend.admin.pricings.zone_edit', compact('zone', 'cities'));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

In your controller's function

```
 $zoneCityIds = [];
 $zone = Zone::find($id);
 $cities = City::all();

 foreach ($zone->cities as $zoneCity)
 { 
  $zoneCityIds[] = $zoneCity->id
 }

 return view('backend.admin.pricings.zone_edit', compact('zone', 'cities','zoneCityIds'));
```

In your view modify your whole loop like below

```
@foreach($cities as $city)
   <option value="{{ $city->id }}" @if(in_array($city->id, $zoneCityIds)) selected @endif>{{ $city->name }}</option>
@endforeach
```

Hope this will help :)

Comment: you save my day it works, but is there any fiture from laravel which can do this without play with array? Something like if collection contain object or something else.

Comment: You should do these kinds of operation in controller, laravel collection is a way but In this case it is not more beneficial

Comment: I Just updated my question, which show my edit controller, maybe you can help me to move this operations in controller.

Comment: Sure. I am trying

Comment: PLease tell me one city belongs to only one zone ? then i can define some modal fucntion and it will be more clean and good code.

Comment: thanks it work, I modified the view to `@foreach($cities as $city)
      @if(in_array($city->id, $zoneCityIds))
         <option value="{{ $city->id }}" selected="true">{{ $city->name }}</option>
         @else
         <option value="{{ $city->id }}">{{ $city->name }}</option>
         @endif 
     @endforeach`

Comment: maybe want to check my other problem about relationship http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40206352/laravel-5-2-how-to-define-relationship-of-3-table

Comment: Will check it today in the night. I am in the office currently (India) :)

Answer (score 0):

You can make this works this way:

```
@foreach($cities as $city)
$currentCity = false;
@foreach($zone->cities as $zone_city)
    @if($city->id == $zone_city->id)
        $currentCity = true;
        <option value="{{ $city->id }}" selected="true">{{ $city->name }}</option>
    @endif  
@endforeach
//if current city id not yet printed before then
@if($currentCity)
<option value="{{ $city->id }}">{{ $city->name }}</option>
@endif
@endforeach
```

But I think this is a better approach, and fit to your need.

```
@foreach($cities as $city)
    @foreach($zone->cities as $zone_city)
        <option value="{{ $city->id }}" @if($city->id == $zone_city->id) selected="true" @endif  >{{ $city->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```