# Laravel 5.2 How laravel treat this belongsto relationship?

Tags: laravel

I have 3 tables, with the fields listed below:

**Pricings**

- id
- route_id

**Routes**

- id
- from_city_id
- to_city_id

**Cities**

- id
- name

So far the relationships of fields are: `pricings belong to a route`, and `routes belongs to city`.

But I'm not sure about these relationships, since `from_city_id` and `to_city_id` are foreign keys relating to `id` on `cities`.

Maybe I'm wrong designing my table or something else.

`route_id` is a foreign key to `id` on the `Routes` table.
`from_city_id` and `to_city_id` are foreign keys to `id` on the `Cities` table.

How I can define relationships of these 3 tables so I can get `from city name` and `to city name` from the pricings model, like `$pricing->from_city->name` and `$pricing->to_city->name`?

Any help appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

My Pricing Model:

```php
public function route()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Route::class);    
}
```

My Route Model:

```php
public function pricing(){
    return $this->hasOne(Pricing::class);    
}

public function zone(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Zone::class);    
}

public function city(){
    return $this->belongsTo(City::class);    
}

public function from_city(){
    return $this->belongsTo(City::class);    
}

public function to_city(){
    return $this->belongsTo(City::class);
}
```

Now I can use `$pricing->route->from_city->name` and `$pricing->route->to_city->name`

It shows the correct result, but how can this be achieved using Laravel?

Does this mean Laravel will assume that the `route` table has fields `to_city_id` and `from_city_id`, since the method in the route model is `to_city()` and `from_city()`?

Thanks

Comment: Have you set up many to many etc?

Comment: @AndyHolmes updated

Comment: I see the belongs, but what about one to many or many to many relationships?

Comment: Is there any reason not using `$pricing->route->from_city->name`?

Answer (score 2):

One solution may be to make a migration (new table or to change to existing table).
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations

Laravel's schema build is super handy:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/schema

An example of the `routes` migration would be:

1. Make the migration:

   php artisan make:migration routes
2. The migration would look something like:

```

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUserRole extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('routes', function (Blueprint $table) {

```
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->foreign('id')->references('route_id')->on('pricings')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->integer('from_city_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('from_city_id')->references('id')->on('cities')->onDelete('no action');             

        $table->integer('to_city_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('to_city_id')->references('id')->on('cities')->onDelete('no action');    

        $table->timestamps();

    });
}
/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('routes');
}
```

}

```

The above for some reason will not show correctly on here, so here is a cleaned up view link: http://viper-7.com/kfgUjt

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

In Pricing Model:

```
//if pricing and route have one to one(hasOne) relationship or you may change it to one to many(hasMany)

public function routes(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Routes','id','route_id'); 
}
```

and in Route Model:

```
public function from_city(){
   return $this->hasOne('App\Cities','id','from_city_id');
}

public function to_city(){
       return $this->hasOne('App\Cities','id','to_city_id');
}
```

Comment: Then how to get `from city name` from pricing model bro? $pricing->????

Comment: $pricing->routes->from_city->name